# When are the elements of a ContentProperty actually created?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, parent-child

I am creating a custom WPF control that uses the following markup:

```
<custom:FilterPanel
    Grid.Row="1"
    FilterTarget="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
    <custom:FilterParameter
        ParameterName="Name"
        TargetProperty="Name" />
    <custom:FilterParameter
        ParameterName="Date"
        TargetProperty="MyDate" />
</custom:FilterPanel>
```

I've set the ContentProperty for my FilterPanel to FilterParameters, which is obviously a collection of FilterParameter objects that I add items to using the markup above.  My question is, when are the elements of a ContentProperty actually processed so that instances are created and items are actually added to the underlying collection?

I'm interested in sharing the data source of the parent control with its children, is there any point in the WPF lifecycle where I can override this behavior and add custom logic to the creation of this collection of FilterParameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class derives from `Panel`, then the first point in the Panel's lifecycle where you can see children (i.e. children that are decalred in XAML like your example - not children generated via bindings) is `Panel.EndInit()`, a virtual method you can override in your derived class. Specifically the chldren created between the `BeginInit` and `EndInit` methods.